# How is the Number of value 0x80000000 organised in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, JavaScript's Number holds a max value of `2^53 - 1`, which is far more than `0x80000000` in case of absolute value.

But here's the code:

```js
let N = 2147483648
console.log(N >> 1)
```

prints:

```
-1073741824
```

What I expected is:

```js
let N = 2147483648
// 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
N >>= 1
// 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The only rule I know may cause this is the bit of sign is filled with `1`, if so, how can it be filled with `1` since left / right shift should fill bits with `0`. Is there any thing to do with the rule that builds the float?

Comment: Where did you get 2^53 from? That's the length of the double floating point mantissa, so it would be the max integer you can represent in a double floating point variable when you need a continuous range of integers from 0, but it's not the actual max value for a double. I would be surprised it JavaScript tried to do bit operations on floating point numbers though.